# Android 10 does not save text file

Tags: java, android

I generated a text file and tried to save it. It doesn't work only on android Q. On android 9 , 8 and 7 it works. When I check if file exists on android 10 it works but I don't it on device  . I do this :

```java
private void createFile(Context ctx, String fileName, String text) {
    File filesDir = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        filesDir = ctx.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
    }
    assert filesDir != null;
    if (!filesDir.exists()){
        if(filesDir.mkdirs()){
        }
    }
    File file = new File(filesDir, fileName + ".txt");
    try {
        if (!file.exists()) {
            if (!file.createNewFile()) {
                throw new IOException("Cant able to create file");
            }
        }
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] data = text.getBytes();
        os.write(data);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        Log.e("TAG", "File Path= " + file.toString());
        if(file.exists()){
            Log.e("d","d");
        }
        File fileTemp = new File(file.getPath());
        FileInputStream notes_xml = new FileInputStream(fileTemp);
        byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int)notes_xml.available()];
//The information will be content on the buffer.

        notes_xml.read(fileContent);

        String strContent = new String(fileContent);
        Log.e("content",strContent);
        notes_xml.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (!file.exists()) {
                if (!file.createNewFile()) {
                    throw new IOException("Cant able to create file");
                }
            }` Remove that code. Its not needed as the file will be created by `new FileOutputStream()`. Are there exceptions? Then the file is created. Where and how did you look to find the file?

Comment: `if(filesDir.mkdirs()){
            }`. That should be: `if(!filesDir.mkdirs()){ Toast( .. could not create directory ..);  return;}`.
            }`

Comment: Place a Toast() in the catch block to inform the user.

Comment: @blackapps I do not see this toast a filesDir.mkdirs() i s true

Comment: Please adapt your code here so we know where we are talking about. Repeat: `Where and how did you look to find the file?` Why dont you answer?

Comment: @blackapps I try find file use file explorer

Comment: You have not adapted your code. You dont wanna be helped?

Comment: @blackapps look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59737911/java-android-q-create-pdf-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-unknown-url

Comment: That is a complete different problem. Solve this one.

Comment: @blackapps but now a file is created