# Java android Q create PDF java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL

Tags: java, android

I want to save a pdf file and my appliation is crashed I did this :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name);
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE, "application/pdf");
            File file = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath());
            Uri imageUri = resolver.insert(Uri.fromFile(file), contentValues);


            fos = resolver.openOutputStream(imageUri);
        }
```

In log I have `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxx.ui.ui.LoginActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/xxx/files/Download`

and this is my provider

```
  <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="xxx.provider"
            android:exported="false"

            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths2" />
        </provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s seems that you create to many slashes in

```
file:///
```

Or this url is not file but directory